# Get next permalink of custom post type – it's not working – tested tons of options – nothing works

Tags: wordpress

I've tried so many different examples of code and nothing is working.
Maybe a corrupted database or am I just doing something fundamentally wrong...

I've tried these on som many others:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
       while ( have_posts() ) {
       the_post(); 
                        
       previous_post_link( '%link', 'Previous post in category', true, ' ');
    
    } 
}



   if ( have_posts() ) {
         while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post(); 
                        
             next_post_link();
    
     }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried `previous_post_link( '%link', 'Previous post in category');` ? 
Your code will search for a next post with the same taxonomy term.

Comment: Why you have two loops ?